# Can memory_order_relaxed atomic stores move above memory_order_release stores?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang++, stdatomic

I've been trying to wrap my head around atomics in C++, and while trying to understand them, I noticed something with a simple example that doesn't make sense to me.

Compiling the sample C++ code...:

```cpp
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> a, b, c;

void variable_release() {
    b.store(123, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    c.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    a.store(1, std::memory_order_release); // release
    b.store(456, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void fence_release() {
    b.store(123, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    c.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); // release
    a.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    b.store(456, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

... results in essentially identical assembly for both GCC (11.2) and Clang (13.0.0), when compiled with `-O3 -march=native`:

```
variable_release():
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 123
        mov     DWORD PTR c[rip], 2
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 456
        ret
fence_release():
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 123
        mov     DWORD PTR c[rip], 2
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 456
        ret
c:
        .zero   4
b:
        .zero   4
a:
        .zero   4
```

I can understand the assembly generation for `fence_release`, due to the following quote from the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence):

> an `atomic_thread_fence` with `memory_order_release` ordering prevents all preceding writes from moving past all subsequent stores.

This would seem to imply that because `c` is written to *after* `b.store(123, ...)`, the second store to `b` can't be reordered above `c.store(...)`, and thus there is no way to avoid the first `b.store(123, ...)` altogether.

However, I don't understand why the first store to `b` still occurs in `variable_release`. I would expect that the second store to `b` can freely move up, above the store to `c`, and thus the redundant store could be eliminated.

Can the write `b.store(123, ...)` be elided in either of these functions? Am I misunderstanding something or is this a missing compiler optimization?

Comment: Title: yes.  But you won't see it at runtime on x86 where in asm every store is at least `release` (which is why the release barrier is zero instructions).  And you don't see it at compile time because compilers don't optimize atomics.  [Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45960387)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: BTW, that definition of release fence is insufficient: it also prevents LoadStore reordering.  But it *does* correctly talk about blocking reordering with any later stores, rather than just one-way wrt. the fence itself, [which would *not* be strong enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193424/224132).

Comment: @PeterCordes The title may be answerable by "yes", but I think the question at the end is not. If I just remove the line with the store, then it could happen that a thread acquiring `a` followed by a read of `b` sees neither of the two stores to `b`, which would not be correct. At least the optimization would need to move the second `b` store before the release.

Comment: @user17732522: Yes, that reordering (dead store elimination of the first store after moving the later store up next to it) is the missed-optimization the question is asking about, which the compiler isn't doing because they never optimize atomics, treating `atomic<T>` basically like `volatile atomic<T>` as well as the other ordering semantics.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oops, sorry. I must have skipped the line where OP already explains this in detail.

Comment: @user17732522: Yup, I've missed my share of details when skimming. :P  I think this question has correct reasoning about everything, so the only missing piece is that compilers choose not to optimize, so it's a duplicate.